# Is it possible to add a text label to an IP address inside a variable without making in unusable?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to ping specific IP Addresses but I would like to label each one so I know what they are adding a label "Server" below but no matter how I try the script will not ping the addresses anymore because of the text I add.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$IPset1 =@(('192.168.0.10' + "Server"),('192.168.0.21' + "Backup"),('192.168.0.43' + "DC"))

```
$IPset1 =@(('192.168.0.10'),('192.168.0.21'),('192.168.0.43'))
$IPset1 =@(('192.168.0.33'),('192.168.0.35'),('192.168.0.38'))

$projectType=Get-ProjectType


foreach($device in $projectType){
if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $device -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
Write-Host "$device is up" -ForegroundColor Green
$output+="$device is up,"+"'n"
}
else{
Write-Host "$device is down" -ForegroundColor Red
$output+="device is down,"+"'n"
}
}
Read-Host - Prompt "Press Enter to Exit"
```

Comment: What is `Get-ProjectType`? That's what you're looping through, and not `$IPset1` (*which the second variable overwrites the first one as well*).

Comment: I didn't post the whole code because it's not relevant but Get-ProjectType is part of the code where I can select which location I want to scan. Thanks

Comment: Try : $IPset1 =@(@('a','192.168.0.10'),@('b','192.168.0.21'),@('c','192.168.0.43'))

Comment: @jdweng, please consider posting your comment as an answer so that it can be marked as the solution.

Comment: $ipset is never used in the code.  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$IPset1 =@(@('a','192.168.0.10'),@('b','192.168.0.21'),@('c','192.168.0.43'))
```

This worked, thank you jdweng